# How can I remove all HTML tags in a string except for the only 's' tag?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove all html tags except only `<s></s>` tags. Right now I have:

`contents.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, '')`

This remove all html tags.

So...

i tried many other solutions.

`<\/?(?!s)\w*\b[^>]*>`. `<(?!s|/s).*?>`.....

However these regex remove all tags containing the letter 's'.

For example, `<strong>` `<span>` and so on.

I'd really appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2691058

Comment: You should look into the [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Comment: Your `<\/?(?!s)\w*\b[^>]*>` seems to be pretty close but you need to add a word boundary after the `s` in the lookahead for not matching e.g. `<span>`... something like [`<\/?\b(?!s\b)[^>]*>`](https://regex101.com/r/eRoXc5/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not this is possible depends on how accurate you want to be. Regex cannot be used to 100% accurately parse HTML.

But if you just want something quick and dirty:

You can take advantage of the fact that `String.prototype.replace` allows you to differentiate between capture groups: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement

So you can make two capture groups:

Group 1 (`<s>` or `</s>`): `<\/?s>`

Group 2: (*"starts with `<`, ends with `>`, and has no `>` between"*): `(<[^>]*>)`

Then when calling `string.replace` return the match if it matches group 1, else it has only matched group 2, so return an empty string:

```js
function removeTags(text) {
  const regex = /(<\/?s>)|(<[^>]*>)/g; // Group 1 OR Group 2
  return text.replace(regex, (_, g1) => g1 || '');
}

let text = '<span>Span Text <s>S Text <strong>Strong Text</strong></s></span>';
console.log(removeTags(text));
```

---

Note the flaw: if `<` and `>` exist as text, everything in between may be considered a tag when it is not:

```js
function removeTags(text) {
  const regex = /(<\/?s>)|(<[^>]*>)/g; // Group 1 OR Group 2
  return text.replace(regex, (_, g1) => g1 || '');
}

let text = '<p> This is how you start a tag: `<` and this is how you end a tag: `>`</p>';
console.log("But the regex fails:");
console.log(removeTags(text));
```

```html
XML parsers can see that the brackets do not create a tag:

<p> This is how you start a tag: `<` and this is how you end a tag: `>`</p>
```

If you want accurate parsing, use an XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You could try: `/(<([^>s]+)>)|(<\/?(\w{2,})>)/gmi`

The first part `(<([^>s]+)>)` will capture all html tags, except tag contain letter `s`.

The second part `(<\/?(\w{2,})>)` will capture all html tags which have 2 letters or more.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/AFlXam/1

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably parse HTML with regex, see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

You can use regex with some limitation to solve your quest of stripping HTML except for `s` tags. This builds upon Chris Hamilton's answer, but avoids falls positives (`a <= 20 && a > 2`) because it is aware of tag and attributes:

```js
function removeTags(text) {
  const regex = /(<\/?s>)|<\/?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?: .*?)?>/g;
  return text.replace(regex, (_, g1) => g1 || '');
}

const text = '<h1>Demo:</h1> <p>Paragraph with <s>S text</s>, <b>bold stuff.</b></p> <p style="color: gray">Condition: <tt>(a <= 20 && a > 2)</tt></p>';
console.log(removeTags(text));
```

Output:

```
Demo: Paragraph with <s>S text</s>, bold stuff. Condition: (a <= 20 && a > 2)
```

Explanation of regex:

- `(<\/?s>)` -- literal `<s>` or `</s>`
- `|` -- logical or
- `<\/?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*` -- start of tag, such as `<h1` or '<p'
- `(?: .*?)?` -- optional non-capture group starting with a space, and a non-greedy scan
- `>` -- literal `>`

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex